# How to convert base64string of image in Byte array using javascript?

Tags: javascript, extjs4

I want convert my base64 string in byte array so that I can sent it to server to store in database...`document.getElementById('userImageId').src` in extjs returens base64 string like `data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSU...........`..How would I convert this into byte array ?

Comment: why don't you send the base64 string to server and decode it there ?

Comment: It will be much easier and simpler to send it as base64 and decode it on the server.

Comment: take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245767/creating-a-blob-from-a-base64-string-in-javascript