# Creating a Blob from a base64 string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, base64

I have base64-encoded binary data in a string.

```javascript
const contentType = 'image/png';
const b64Data = 'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==';
```

I would like to create a `blob:` URL containing this data and display it to the user.

```javascript
const blob = new Blob(????, {type: contentType});
const blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

window.location = blobUrl;
```

I haven't been able to figure out how to create the `Blob`.

In some cases, I can avoid this by using a `data:` URL instead.

```javascript
const dataUrl = `data:${contentType};base64,${b64Data}`;

window.location = dataUrl;
```

However in most cases the `data:` URLs are prohibitively large.

---

How can I decode a base64 string to a `Blob` object in JavaScript?

Answer (score 1142, accepted):

The `atob` function will decode a base64-encoded string into a new string with a character for each byte of the binary data.

```javascript
const byteCharacters = atob(b64Data);
```

Each character's code point (charCode) will be the value of the byte. We can create an array of byte values by applying this using the `.charCodeAt` method for each character in the string.

```javascript
const byteNumbers = new Array(byteCharacters.length);
for (let i = 0; i < byteCharacters.length; i++) {
    byteNumbers[i] = byteCharacters.charCodeAt(i);
}
```

You can convert this array of byte values into a real typed byte array by passing it to the `Uint8Array` constructor.

```javascript
const byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
```

This in turn can be converted to a `Blob` by wrapping it in an array and passing it to the `Blob` constructor.

```javascript
const blob = new Blob([byteArray], {type: contentType});
```

The code above works. However the performance can be improved a little by processing the `byteCharacters` in smaller slices, rather than all at once. In my rough testing 512 bytes seems to be a good slice size. This gives us the following function.

```javascript
const b64toBlob = (b64Data, contentType='', sliceSize=512) => {
  const byteCharacters = atob(b64Data);
  const byteArrays = [];

  for (let offset = 0; offset < byteCharacters.length; offset += sliceSize) {
    const slice = byteCharacters.slice(offset, offset + sliceSize);

    const byteNumbers = new Array(slice.length);
    for (let i = 0; i < slice.length; i++) {
      byteNumbers[i] = slice.charCodeAt(i);
    }

    const byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
    byteArrays.push(byteArray);
  }
    
  const blob = new Blob(byteArrays, {type: contentType});
  return blob;
}
```

```javascript
const blob = b64toBlob(b64Data, contentType);
const blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

window.location = blobUrl;
```

#### Full Example:

```js
const b64toBlob = (b64Data, contentType='', sliceSize=512) => {
  const byteCharacters = atob(b64Data);
  const byteArrays = [];

  for (let offset = 0; offset < byteCharacters.length; offset += sliceSize) {
    const slice = byteCharacters.slice(offset, offset + sliceSize);

    const byteNumbers = new Array(slice.length);
    for (let i = 0; i < slice.length; i++) {
      byteNumbers[i] = slice.charCodeAt(i);
    }

    const byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
    byteArrays.push(byteArray);
  }
    
  const blob = new Blob(byteArrays, {type: contentType});
  return blob;
}

const contentType = 'image/png';
const b64Data = 'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==';

const blob = b64toBlob(b64Data, contentType);
const blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

const img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = blobUrl;
document.body.appendChild(img);
```

Comment: Hi Jeremy. We have had this code in our web application and it didn't cause any problem until the files being downloaded were larger in size. So it caused hangs and crashes in production server, when users were using Chrome or IE to download files larger than 100mb. We found that the in IE following line was raising memory exception "var byteNumbers = new Array(slice.length)". However in chrome, it was the for loop causing same issue. We couldn't find a proper resolution to this issue then we moved to directly downloading files using window.open. Can you provide some help here?

Comment: this didn't work for me for some blobs on Chrome and Firefox but worked on edge:/

Comment: This worked for me for images but didn't work for mp4 video. Does anyone have a clue how can I convert video base64 string to blob? Any help appreciated!

Comment: `atop` seems deprecated. Better use `Buffer.from(data ,'base64')`

Comment: charCodeAt on a buffer doesn't seem to work

Comment: Hey Jeremy, can you take a look at <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77319291/how-to-send-an-excel-spreadsheet-from-backend-api-to-angular-front-end-to-downlo>?

Answer (score 625):

Here is a more minimal method without any dependencies or libraries.
It requires the new fetch API. ([Can I use it?](http://caniuse.com/#search=fetch))

```js
var url = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="

fetch(url)
.then(res => res.blob())
.then(console.log)
```

With this method you can also easily get a ReadableStream, ArrayBuffer, text, and JSON.
(fyi this also works with [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch) in Node)

As a function:

```js
const b64toBlob = (base64, type = 'application/octet-stream') => 
  fetch(`data:${type};base64,${base64}`).then(res => res.blob())
```

But I would encourage you to **don't use base64 in the first place**. There are better ways to send and receive binary data. JSON isn't always the best option. it takes up more bandwidth and waste processing time (de)encodeing stuff. Us eg `canvas.toBlob` instead of `canvas.toDataURL` and use `FormData` to send binary files. you can also return back a multipart payload and decode it using `await response.formData()` that is coming from a server response. FormData can go both ways.

---

I did a simple performance test towards Jeremy's ES6 sync version.
The sync version will block UI for a while.
keeping the devtool open can slow the fetch performance

```js
document.body.innerHTML += '<input autofocus placeholder="try writing">'
// get some dummy gradient image
var img=function(){var a=document.createElement("canvas"),b=a.getContext("2d"),c=b.createLinearGradient(0,0,1500,1500);a.width=a.height=3000;c.addColorStop(0,"red");c.addColorStop(1,"blue");b.fillStyle=c;b.fillRect(0,0,a.width,a.height);return a.toDataURL()}();


async function perf() {
  
  const blob = await fetch(img).then(res => res.blob())
  // turn it to a dataURI
  const url = img
  const b64Data = url.split(',')[1]

  // Jeremy Banks solution
  const b64toBlob = (b64Data, contentType = '', sliceSize=512) => {
    const byteCharacters = atob(b64Data);
    const byteArrays = [];
    
    for (let offset = 0; offset < byteCharacters.length; offset += sliceSize) {
      const slice = byteCharacters.slice(offset, offset + sliceSize);
      
      const byteNumbers = new Array(slice.length);
      for (let i = 0; i < slice.length; i++) {
        byteNumbers[i] = slice.charCodeAt(i);
      }
      
      const byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
      
      byteArrays.push(byteArray);
    }
    
    const blob = new Blob(byteArrays, {type: contentType});
    return blob;
  }

  // bench blocking method
  let i = 500
  console.time('blocking b64')
  while (i--) {
    await b64toBlob(b64Data)
  }
  console.timeEnd('blocking b64')
  
  // bench non blocking
  i = 500

  // so that the function is not reconstructed each time
  const toBlob = res => res.blob()
  console.time('fetch')
  while (i--) {
    await fetch(url).then(toBlob)
  }
  console.timeEnd('fetch')
  console.log('done')
}

perf()
```

Comment: Will this still work if the size of the base64-encoded string is large, let's say larger than 665536 characters, which is the limit for URI sizes in Opera?

Comment: Don't know, I know it can be a limit to the adressbar but doing things with AJAX might be an exception since it don't have to be rendered. You have to test it. If it where me i would never had gotten the base64 string in the first place. Thinking it's a bad practice, takes up more memory and time to decode and encode. `createObjectURL` instead of `readAsDataURL` is much better for example. And if you upload files using ajax, choose `FormData` instead of `JSON`, or use `canvas.toBlob` instead of `toDataURL`

Comment: Even better as inline: `await (await fetch(imageDataURL)).blob()`

Comment: sure, if you target the latest browser. But that requires the function to be inside a async function also. Speaking of... `await fetch(url).then(r=>r.blob())` is sorter

Comment: Very neat solution, but according to my knowledge won't work with IE (with polyfill ofc) due to `Access is denied.` error. I guess `fetch` exposes blob under blob url - in the same way `URL.createObjectUrl` does - which won't work on ie11. [reference](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/all/unable-to-preview-the-pdf-filecontent-using-blob/ba1806e8-307e-4b8f-92d1-b986f5537052). Maybe there is some workaround to use fetch with IE11? It looks much better than other sync solutions :)

Comment: This doesn't work in react-native, and whatwg-fetch version over 2.0.4 is coming with a bug, so it's mainly a browser solution.

Comment: If anyone is still looking for a ie11-cross-browser solution please take a look at my answer below https://stackoverflow.com/a/54037351/6733608

Comment: node-fetch call to base64url throws `Only HTTP(S) protocols are supported`

Comment: @CristianG maybe try v3?

Comment: @Endless It's not shorter if you do a fair comparison with `await (await fetch(url)).blob()`.

Comment: Why `image/png`?

Answer (score 108):

Optimized (but less readable) implementation:

```js
function base64toBlob(base64Data, contentType) {
    contentType = contentType || '';
    var sliceSize = 1024;
    var byteCharacters = atob(base64Data);
    var bytesLength = byteCharacters.length;
    var slicesCount = Math.ceil(bytesLength / sliceSize);
    var byteArrays = new Array(slicesCount);

    for (var sliceIndex = 0; sliceIndex < slicesCount; ++sliceIndex) {
        var begin = sliceIndex * sliceSize;
        var end = Math.min(begin + sliceSize, bytesLength);

        var bytes = new Array(end - begin);
        for (var offset = begin, i = 0; offset < end; ++i, ++offset) {
            bytes[i] = byteCharacters[offset].charCodeAt(0);
        }
        byteArrays[sliceIndex] = new Uint8Array(bytes);
    }
    return new Blob(byteArrays, { type: contentType });
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason for slicing the bytes into blobs? If I don't use, is there any disadvantage or risk?

Comment: Works great on Android with Ionic 1 / Angular 1. Slice is required otherwise I run into OOM (Android 6.0.1).

Comment: Only example out there I could get to work seamlessly with any document type in an enterprise environment in both IE 11 and Chrome.

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., why does it have higher performance?

Comment: @PeterMortensen It was several years ago, for now you could try to perf several variants.
Idea was in reorganization cycle condition checks and local variables.

Comment: Tested, about 50% drop in performance on IE11 and almost 100% drop in performance on chrome compared to the accepted answer. Note that chrome was about 5 times faster than IE11. I don't have any idea why this "optimized" answer got so many up votes.

Comment: @zoran404 It's strange. Can you provide test cases when you reached degradation in performance?
On my common workload I have performance boost on +3.4% (ops).
My test suite is:
Version from original (accepted) answer:
https://gist.github.com/bacher/426e9b0d3343498a911ac726559c6931 ,
My (optimized) version:
https://gist.github.com/bacher/8494b2607305ecd77e3d6af300ce6d90 .
I see performance increase in range +2.7% – +3.4% (depends on run...), average boost: +3.05%.
Testing environment is Chrome Version 94.0.4606.71 (Official Build) (x86_64) on MacOS.

Comment: @zoran404 I suppose what your performance issues can be tied with non optimal `sliceSize` for your workload, in my code I always use 1024, but in accepted answer it can be set manually and  default value is 512.

Answer (score 41):

Following is my TypeScript code which can be converted easily into JavaScript and you can use

```js
/**
 * Convert BASE64 to BLOB
 * @param base64Image Pass Base64 image data to convert into the BLOB
 */
private convertBase64ToBlob(base64Image: string) {
  // Split into two parts
  const parts = base64Image.split(';base64,');

  // Hold the content type
  const imageType = parts[0].split(':')[1];

  // Decode Base64 string
  const decodedData = window.atob(parts[1]);

  // Create UNIT8ARRAY of size same as row data length
  const uInt8Array = new Uint8Array(decodedData.length);

  // Insert all character code into uInt8Array
  for (let i = 0; i < decodedData.length; ++i) {
    uInt8Array[i] = decodedData.charCodeAt(i);
  }

  // Return BLOB image after conversion
  return new Blob([uInt8Array], { type: imageType });
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 26):

For all copy-paste lovers out there like me, here is a cooked download function which works on Chrome, Firefox and Edge:

```
window.saveFile = function (bytesBase64, mimeType, fileName) {
var fileUrl = "data:" + mimeType + ";base64," + bytesBase64;
fetch(fileUrl)
    .then(response => response.blob())
    .then(blob => {
        var link = window.document.createElement("a");
        link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob, { type: mimeType });
        link.download = fileName;
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.click();
        document.body.removeChild(link);
    });
}
```

Comment: and safari (at least on desktop)

Comment: Thank's for answer and this code is sample:
 `fetch(base64)`
          `.then((response) => response.blob())`
          `.then((blob) => {`
            `const blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);`
            `window.open(blobUrl);`
          `});`

Answer (score 23):

For all browser support, especially on Android, perhaps you can add this:

```
try{
    blob = new Blob(byteArrays, {type : contentType});
}
catch(e){
    // TypeError old Google Chrome and Firefox
    window.BlobBuilder = window.BlobBuilder ||
                         window.WebKitBlobBuilder ||
                         window.MozBlobBuilder ||
                         window.MSBlobBuilder;
    if(e.name == 'TypeError' && window.BlobBuilder){
        var bb = new BlobBuilder();
        bb.append(byteArrays);
        blob = bb.getBlob(contentType);
    }
    else if(e.name == "InvalidStateError"){
        // InvalidStateError (tested on FF13 WinXP)
        blob = new Blob(byteArrays, {type : contentType});
    }
    else{
        // We're screwed, blob constructor unsupported entirely
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but there are TWO issues on the code snippet you wrote above if I read it correctly: (1) The code within catch() on the last else-if is the same as the original code within try(): "blob = new Blob(byteArrays, {type : contentType})" ... I dunno why you suggest to repeat the same code after original exception? ... (2)  BlobBuilder.append() can NOT accept bytes-arrays but ArrayBuffer. So, the input bytes-arrays must be converted further into its ArrayBuffer before using this API. REF: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BlobBuilder

Answer (score 23):

See this example: https://jsfiddle.net/pqhdce2L/

```js
function b64toBlob(b64Data, contentType, sliceSize) {
  contentType = contentType || '';
  sliceSize = sliceSize || 512;

  var byteCharacters = atob(b64Data);
  var byteArrays = [];

  for (var offset = 0; offset < byteCharacters.length; offset += sliceSize) {
    var slice = byteCharacters.slice(offset, offset + sliceSize);

    var byteNumbers = new Array(slice.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < slice.length; i++) {
      byteNumbers[i] = slice.charCodeAt(i);
    }

    var byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);

    byteArrays.push(byteArray);
  }
    
  var blob = new Blob(byteArrays, {type: contentType});
  return blob;
}


var contentType = 'image/png';
var b64Data = Your Base64 encode;

var blob = b64toBlob(b64Data, contentType);
var blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

var img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = blobUrl;
document.body.appendChild(img);
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order.

Answer (score 18):

If you can stand adding one dependency to your project there's the great [`blob-util` npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/blob-util) that provides a handy `base64StringToBlob` function. Once added to your `package.json` you can use it like this:

```
import { base64StringToBlob } from 'blob-util';

const contentType = 'image/png';
const b64Data = 'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==';

const blob = base64StringToBlob(b64Data, contentType);

// Do whatever you need with your blob...
```

Comment: This answer worked for me using Angular 12 in 2021

Answer (score 17):

For image data, I find it simpler to use `canvas.toBlob` (asynchronous)

```
function b64toBlob(b64, onsuccess, onerror) {
    var img = new Image();

    img.onerror = onerror;

    img.onload = function onload() {
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.width = img.width;
        canvas.height = img.height;

        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        canvas.toBlob(onsuccess);
    };

    img.src = b64;
}

var base64Data = 'data:image/jpg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQA...';
b64toBlob(base64Data,
    function(blob) {
        var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        // do something with url
    }, function(error) {
        // handle error
    });
```

Comment: I guess you loose some information with that... like the meta info its like converting any image to png, so it isn't the same result, also this only works for images

Comment: I guess you could improve it by extracting image type `image/jpg` from the base64 string and then pass it as a second parameter into `toBlob` function so that the result is same type. Other than that I think this is perfect - it saves 30% of traffic and your disk space on the server (compared to base64) and it works nice even with transparent PNG.

Comment: The function crashes with images larger than 2MB... in Android I get the exception: android.os.TransactionTooLarge

Answer (score 17):

I'm posting a more declarative way of sync Base64 converting. While async `fetch().blob()` is very neat and I like this solution a lot, it doesn't work on Internet Explorer 11 (and probably Edge - I haven't tested this one), even with the polyfill - take a look at my comment to [Endless' post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245767/creating-a-blob-from-a-base64-string-in-javascript/36183085#36183085) for more details.

```
const blobPdfFromBase64String = base64String => {
   const byteArray = Uint8Array.from(
     atob(base64String)
       .split('')
       .map(char => char.charCodeAt(0))
   );
  return new Blob([byteArray], { type: 'application/pdf' });
};
```

#### Bonus

If you want to print it you could do something like:

```
const isIE11 = !!(window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob); // Or however you want to check it
const printPDF = blob => {
   try {
     isIE11
       ? window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, 'documents.pdf')
       : printJS(URL.createObjectURL(blob)); // http://printjs.crabbly.com/
   } catch (e) {
     throw PDFError;
   }
};
```

#### Bonus x 2 - Opening a BLOB file in new tab for Internet Explorer 11

If you're able to do some preprocessing of the Base64 string on the server you could expose it under some URL and use the link in `printJS` :)

Comment: can inform you that Edge works, Edge is now chromium based so it should support most things chrome can do

Answer (score 14):

I noticed that Internet Explorer 11 gets incredibly slow when slicing the data like Jeremy suggested. This is true for Chrome, but Internet Explorer seems to have a problem when passing the sliced data to the Blob-Constructor. On my machine, passing 5 MB of data makes Internet Explorer crash and memory consumption is going through the roof. Chrome creates the blob in no time.

Run this code for a comparison:

```
var byteArrays = [],
    megaBytes = 2,
    byteArray = new Uint8Array(megaBytes*1024*1024),
    block,
    blobSlowOnIE, blobFastOnIE,
    i;

for (i = 0; i < (megaBytes*1024); i++) {
    block = new Uint8Array(1024);
    byteArrays.push(block);
}

//debugger;

console.profile("No Slices");
blobSlowOnIE = new Blob(byteArrays, { type: 'text/plain'});
console.profileEnd();

console.profile("Slices");
blobFastOnIE = new Blob([byteArray], { type: 'text/plain'});
console.profileEnd();
```

So I decided to include both methods described by Jeremy in one function. Credits go to him for this.

```
function base64toBlob(base64Data, contentType, sliceSize) {

    var byteCharacters,
        byteArray,
        byteNumbers,
        blobData,
        blob;

    contentType = contentType || '';

    byteCharacters = atob(base64Data);

    // Get BLOB data sliced or not
    blobData = sliceSize ? getBlobDataSliced() : getBlobDataAtOnce();

    blob = new Blob(blobData, { type: contentType });

    return blob;


    /*
     * Get BLOB data in one slice.
     * => Fast in Internet Explorer on new Blob(...)
     */
    function getBlobDataAtOnce() {
        byteNumbers = new Array(byteCharacters.length);

        for (var i = 0; i < byteCharacters.length; i++) {
            byteNumbers[i] = byteCharacters.charCodeAt(i);
        }

        byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);

        return [byteArray];
    }

    /*
     * Get BLOB data in multiple slices.
     * => Slow in Internet Explorer on new Blob(...)
     */
    function getBlobDataSliced() {

        var slice,
            byteArrays = [];

        for (var offset = 0; offset < byteCharacters.length; offset += sliceSize) {
            slice = byteCharacters.slice(offset, offset + sliceSize);

            byteNumbers = new Array(slice.length);

            for (var i = 0; i < slice.length; i++) {
                byteNumbers[i] = slice.charCodeAt(i);
            }

            byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);

            // Add slice
            byteArrays.push(byteArray);
        }

        return byteArrays;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for including this. With a recent update to IE11 (between 5/2016 and 8/2016), generating blobs from arrays began taking a magnitude greater amount of ram. By sending a single Uint8Array into the blog constructor, it used almost no ram and actually completed the process.

Comment: Increasing slice size in test sample from 1K to 8..16K significantly decreases time in IE. On my PC original code took from 5 to 8 seconds, code with 8K blocks took only 356ms, and 225ms for 16K blocks

Answer (score 12):

The method with fetch is the best solution, but if anyone needs to use a method without fetch then here it is, as the ones mentioned previously didn't work for me:

```
function makeblob(dataURL) {
    const BASE64_MARKER = ';base64,';
    const parts = dataURL.split(BASE64_MARKER);
    const contentType = parts[0].split(':')[1];
    const raw = window.atob(parts[1]);
    const rawLength = raw.length;
    const uInt8Array = new Uint8Array(rawLength);

    for (let i = 0; i < rawLength; ++i) {
        uInt8Array[i] = raw.charCodeAt(i);
    }

    return new Blob([uInt8Array], { type: contentType });
}
```

Answer (score 9):

In browser just

```js
Uint8Array.from(atob(YOUR_BASE64_DATA), (c) => c.charCodeAt(0))
```

compare with `fetch`

```js
!(async () => {
  const start = performance.now();
  let i = 0;
  while (i++ < 1e3) {
    const dataUrl =
      "data:application/octet-stream;base64,H4sIAAAAAAAAA0vOzyvOz0nVy8lP10jISM3JyVdIr8osUFCpdkksSdXLyy/X0KxN0ORKHlU3qm5U3ai6UXWj6kauOgBVt1KRLwcAAA==";
    body = await (await fetch(dataUrl)).blob();
  }
  console.log(performance.now() - start); // 508.19999999925494ms
})();
```

```js
!(async () => {
  const start = performance.now();
  let i = 0;
  while (i++ < 1e3) {
    const base64Data =
      "H4sIAAAAAAAAA0vOzyvOz0nVy8lP10jISM3JyVdIr8osUFCpdkksSdXLyy/X0KxN0ORKHlU3qm5U3ai6UXWj6kauOgBVt1KRLwcAAA==";
    body = Uint8Array.from(atob(base64Data), (c) => c.charCodeAt(0));
  }
  console.log(performance.now() - start); // 7.899999998509884ms
})();
```

**Depends on your data size, choose performance one.**

Answer (score 4):

Two different variations

```
function base64ToBlob(base64, contentType='image/png', chunkLength=512) {
    const byteCharsArray = Array.from(atob(base64.substr(base64.indexOf(',') + 1)));
    const chunksIterator = new Array(Math.ceil(byteCharsArray.length / chunkLength));
    const bytesArrays = [];

    for (let c = 0; c < chunksIterator.length; c++) {
        bytesArrays.push(new Uint8Array(byteCharsArray.slice(c * chunkLength, chunkLength * (c + 1)).map(s => s.charCodeAt(0))));
    }

    const blob = new Blob(bytesArrays, {type: contentType});
    
    return blob;
}

/* Not sure how it performs with big images */
async function base64ToBlobLight(base64) { return await fetch(base64).then(res => res.blob()); }

/* Test */
const base64Data = 'data:image/png;base64,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';
        
const blob = base64ToBlob(base64Data);
const blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
const img = document.createElement('img');

img.src = blobUrl;
document.body.appendChild(img);

/**********************/

/* Test */
(async () => {
    const blob = await base64ToBlobLight(base64Data);
    const blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    const img = document.createElement('img');

    img.src = blobUrl;
    document.body.appendChild(img);
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

Excellent contribution

Since the functions [slice, atob] were deprecated. I have made an update to the code suggested by Jeremy

```
  base64toBlob(
    dataURI: string,
    contentType = '',
    sliceSize = 512,
  ) {
    const byteCharacters = Buffer.from(dataURI, 'binary');
    const byteArrays = [];

    for (let offset = 0; offset < byteCharacters.length; offset += sliceSize) {
      const slice = byteCharacters.subarray(offset, offset + sliceSize);

      const byteArray = Uint8Array.prototype.slice.call(slice);
      byteArrays.push(byteArray);
    }

    const blob = new Blob(byteArrays, { type: contentType });
    return blob;
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

This would prove to be much short solution.

```
const byteArray = new Buffer(base64String.replace(/^[\w\d;:\/]+base64\,/g, ''), 'base64');
```

> base64String is the string containing the base 64 string.

> byteArray is the array you need.

> The regex replacement is optional and is just there to deal with prefix as in the case of dataurl string.

Comment: This creates a Node JS `Buffer` object and not a browser `blob:` url.
Additionally, there is no reason to set the `/g` global flag on the regex, you are only matching the beginning, up to one time.